# Why Dirac monopole is a topological defect in a $U(1)$ gauge theory?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, topology, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole

1. How does $U(1)$ gauge group at long distances, give rise to [magnetic monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole)?
2. Also ***why is it said that Dirac monopole is a topological defect in a compact $U(1)$ gauge theory?***